# Refresh social div without refreshing whole page

Tags: javascript, ajax

I did some searches about this topic and most solution have another html involve. Mine hoever involve only one page html. Here it is.

My Current code in index.html

```
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function () { 
      location.reload(true);
    }, 20 * 1000);
</script>

<div id="wall">
    <div id="igstream"></div>
</div>

</body>
```

This page auto refresh the whole page every 20 seconds. igstream is a div that is being updated everytime someone post with targeted hashtag. So for example I visit

```
index.html?tags=tagsforlikes
```

The page will show images from Instagram with tags=tagsforlikes and will refresh every 20 seconds to be able to display new post from instagram with tags=tagsforlikes

This works so far for now but I want to enhance it by refreshing only the div part

```
<div id="igstream"></div>
```

I want to do this because I redesign the page which includes large image background on the page. Hoping to save bandwidth by being able to refresh only the div part.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use, jquery `load()` function,

```
$( "#igstream" ).load( "yourfile link here" );
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is the easiest way to do that. Just put the social part into a page that only holds the content, and use elem.innerHTML to update it after you have the new content.

Comment: sounds interesting. can you give a sample? Thanks

Comment: @CharlesWayne, I could give you an example, but it wouldn't help you much. Because you can't separate the new content into another page, you'll need to "dig through" each page reload, and get just want you want. W3Schools is a great place to start with this, and Google after that. http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Answer (score 0):

the only way I can think you will be able to do this is with an ajax call, this is using jquery for simplicity but you could do it many different ways.

```
$url = ''; //wherever you are getting the data from.
var request = $.ajax({
  url: $url,
  type: "GET",
});
request.done(function(r) {
/// update your div with retrieved content in "r"
});
```

Comment: **//wherever you are getting the data from.** same url that I need to refresh

Comment: your page is your source? It sounds more like instagram is the source data. You should use the isntagram API
example URL
$tag = 'tagsforlikes'
$token = '' //instagram token get from instagram.com/developer/
$count = 20 //number of items to return
$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'.$tag.'/media/recent/?access_token=$token&count='.$count;

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  window.setInterval(function(){
  $( "#igstream" ).load( "index.html?tags=tagsforlikes" );
  }, 20 * 1000);
</script>

<div id="wall">
    <div id="igstream"></div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this approach adds the whole page again and again with its head elements. I need something that will reload igstream part only to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

```
 window.setInterval(function(){
 $( "#igstream").load("test.html");
 }, 1000);
```

This will refresh your div 'igstream' with content in test.html every 1000 milli seconds